# tftp “Successful Transfer” but file incomplete (windows 7 client put to ubuntu tftpd-hpa server)

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I'm trying to transfer a file using the Windows 7 tftp client (from the command line: tftp  put  ) to a tftp server in Ubuntu 12.04 (tftpd-hpa with TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure -c").

The windows client returns: "Transfer successful: 524 bytes in 1 second(s), 524 bytes/s" but the file is actually 297 KB.

I tried a different file (298 KB) but only 143 KB were transferred.

I've been able to transfer smaller files (273 bytes) in the past with no issues.

At this point I'm not sure what to look for. I know tftp used to have a size limit in the past but I don't believe this is my issue.

(From Wikipedia:

The original protocol has a file size limit of 32 MB. In 1998 this limit was extended to 4 GB by RFC 2347 which introduced option negotiation and RFC 2348 which introduced block-size negotiation. If the server and client support block number wraparound, file size is essentially unlimited.)

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work but I found a work around by adding the -i option which is used for bite to bite image transfer, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work but I found a work around by adding the -i option which is used for bite to bite image transfer, etc.